# Fail to start Azure Service Fabric Host Service (FabricHostSvc)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

On Windows 7, with `VS 2013` and `VS 2015` I try to install and run *Service Fabric*.

First try SDK and Tools - 2.4.164 after install VS 2015, then uninstall and try just with SDK 2.3.311 with same result.

Then I try permissions and Fabric counters scheduled task search, all with same result in every case:
[Error when run cluster setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Dla.png)

All those cases create two `fabricdeployer-numbers.trace` files without errors and several `FabricSetup-number.trace` with this content:

```
 2017-02-10 21:18:46.020,Info    ,9176,General.FabricSetup.Main,FabricSetup.exe invoked with arguments (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\FabricSetup.exe /operation:addnodestate). Current Exe version 5.3.311.9590
    2017-02-10 21:18:46.021,Info    ,9176,General.FabricSetup.Main,Environment information Data Root C:\SfDevCluster\Data, Log Root C:\SfDevCluster\Log
    2017-02-10 21:18:46.022,Info    ,9176,FabricSetup.FabricSetup.ServiceManager,Starting service eventlog
    2017-02-10 21:18:46.023,Info    ,9176,FabricSetup.FabricSetup.ServiceManager,Starting service pla
    2017-02-10 21:18:46.023,Error   ,9176,FabricSetup.FabricSetup.ServiceManager,Error 0x80070422 while starting service 'pla'
    2017-02-10 21:18:46.023,Warning ,9176,General.FabricSetup.Main,Unable to start pla service because of error 0x80070422
    2017-02-10 21:18:46.023,Error   ,9176,General.FabricSetup.Main,Failed the pre-requisite check for fabric setup
    2017-02-10 21:18:46.023,Noise   ,9176,Common.MutexHandle@3aff50,released
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x80070422 is ERROR_SERVICE_DISABLED, in services.msc can you see if the "Performance Logs & Alerts" service is present and set to automatically start with Windows?

Comment: Also make sure Task Scheduler service is running.